# preg_replace a string that's not inside quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this string:

```
$str = "<script> alert( 'Alert 1' ); alert( 'Alert 2' ); </script>";
```

I'm doing a preg_replace to remove the spaces in the string:

```
$str = preg_replace('% %', '', $str);
```

But I'm not sure how to modify the regex (if possible!) to tell it to ignore any spaces inside single quotes.

Comment: _"remove the spaces in the string"_ <- why? It will change nothing functionally

Comment: The reason why is irrelevant. I'm providing a minimal example of my code. Don't worry about the why!

Comment: @IdontDownVote I think OP wants to maintain the spaces in "Alert 1" and "Alert 2"

Comment: Correct, but I thought that was obvious?

Comment: I feel like this is a question that has been asked before. What have your searches turned up? From the results (if any), what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this regex,

```
[ ](?=([^\"']*[\"'][^\"']*[\"'])*[^\"']*$)
```